# how to get the next image tag after specific dom tag, sibling or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say for code such as

```
<html>
<h1>heading</h1>
<div>
  <div>
      <span>
            <img src="source"/>
       </span>
  </div>
</div>
 </html>
```

The above is just an example, it should work for any html code. 
I need the next image tag after `<h1>` no matter where the `img` is placed
 
`$('h1').nextAll('img').first()` or `$('h1').nextUntil('img').last().next()` won't work here because they are not siblings of `<h1>`. Is there a way I can get the `img` without writing too much loop code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $h1 = $("h1"); // Your `h1`
var all = $("*"); // All DOM elements

var h1idx = all.index($h1);
all.splice(0, h1idx); // Get rid of everything before and until your `h1`

var result = all.filter("img").first(); // Your first `img`
```

Comment: Downvoter: it would be helpful to the community if you would please comment with your thoughts.

Comment: Unrelated to your answer, but why wasn't that a dupe? The snippet couldn't be used as is, but didn't the general idea apply?

Comment: Hi, @Stijn. It's subjective, to say the least, to assert that the *general idea applied*. While I definitely agree that the top answer has some very helpful leads, the question does not pose a duplicate problem.

Comment: just wondering..why did you splice out elements before `<h1>`.. just running filter on `img` wont work?

Comment: @wolfgang Because otherwise `img`s before the `h1` will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var img_after_h1 = $("* > h1 + * img");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/T7AqX/

Edit

Varied `html` structures, nested `h1` `element`, multiple `img` tags, test-cases.
Work for `html` structure from original post, as well

```
var img = $("h1 ~ img, h1 ~ * img, *:has(h1) + * + img, *:has(h1) ~ * img")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aBRjL/

Comment: This is incorrect. It will only match children of the element after `h1`.

Comment: On that particular example, it does. What if there's an empty `div` after an `h1`? It does **not** work in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/gqg8V/.

Comment: @Chri Good points. Was unaware how "deep" the search might proceed. Forked jsfiddle link from Chris, adjusted "siblings" selector, will update post, see http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3MZsB/

Comment: @guest271314 Nice. Closer, but still not quite there yet. ;) http://jsfiddle.net/tgVx8/

Comment: @Chris Interesting. The above jsfiddle, perhaps  may a) be different `html` structure than the original post; b) does not include or reference clear requirement stated or defined, i.e.g., "the requirement is retrieval _2_ `img` `src`'s adjacent to, or siblings of an `h1` element" ? Thanks !

Comment: @guest271314 Well, the example mainly shows that the current selector will not match sibling `img`s.

Comment: @Chris Not certain which `selector` referring to. _Both_ jsfiddle pieces, at post "match" selector provided at original post. Original post did not include, as best as can discern, additional test cases for the viability of the selector ? Nor, how "deep" the selector should traverse ? At either jsfiddle's posted, the output is appended to document. Including additional test case parameters might always require adjustments - especially if several test-cases added without clear requirement ? Happy to try test cases, where `html` and requirement clearly defined, notpresent at comments & jsfiddles

Comment: The question says: `need the next image tag after <h1> no matter where the img is placed`. The [jsFiddle I shared above](http://jsfiddle.net/tgVx8/) has an `img` after `h1`, and it does not get matched.

Comment: @Chris. Not certain where going here ? Again, totally different `html` structure ? Different requirement ? The relevant question _might_ be "match 1st `img` after `h1` _and_ 2nd `img` after `h1` ?" Again, happy to try test cases, for purity of it, yet inserting additional `html` without clearly defining requirement challenging. Not impossible, but challenging, where in "question" or "comment" form - espcially when several test-cases compounded ? Again, if `html` from above comment jsfiddle would have been in question form with said requirement, that may have been `target` of selection ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 Hmm, let me try to rephrase this. In the jsFiddle, there's an `img` with a `src` of `firstsource`, and it is the first `img` after the `h1`. The current script does not match that image. Instead, it only matches the **second** `img` that is a child (because of the jQuery selector you're using) -- namely the one that has a `src` of `secondsource`.

Comment: @Chris Again, not certain where going here ? The post, believe, fulfills the requirements of the originally posted `html` - and the originally posted question. Was _not_ _second_ `img` in original post. That was test-case from comment. Again, happy to try test cases, yet nearly impossible if actual `html` structure changes, or changes simply to test different cases. Ok, with that, yet not part and parcel of original question. More of a refinement of original question, from practical view ? If gather accurately, as relatively new to so,the guideline is to answer only actual posted question ?

Comment: @Chris For completeness and clarity, as to last jsfiddle at comments, this should match `img` after `h1` `var img = $("* > h1 ~ img").attr("src");` Just removed the `*`, as, again, is different `html` structure traversing jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3W6Jp/. Thanks for sharing

Comment: @guest271314 Correct, it would. However, as far as I understand, the solution to the OP's problem would match the first `img` after the `h1` in **ANY** structure or positioning, without modifying the selector for every HTML structure and special case.

Comment: @Chris Interesting perspective. Probably the appropriate approach, yet, if `html` is posted, in general, at least here, try to formulate a possible response based on `html` provided - or, if `html` not provided, ask that `html` be posted. Get the perspective presented, and would probably approach question different with the above comment on table, to an appreciable degree. Perhaps, just gather all `img`s then filter siblings that are `h1`. Again, `html` structure may alter approach if `html` posted. Is a portion of comment,if interpret as potential suggestion,compose with test case possibles?

Comment: @Chris `var img = $("h1 ~ img, h1 ~ * img").attr("src");` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3W6Jp/

Comment: @guest271313 that would not work if your `h1` is nested within some other element and the `img` is within a sibling of the `h1` parent.

Comment: @Chris If get chance, please fork jsfiddle and post comment demonstrating test-case ? Appears to work, there. Perhaps  Thanks note all possible test-cases, html structures ? Perhaps requirement would be single `$()` selector ?

Comment: @Chris `var img = $("*:has(h1) + * + img")` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aBRjL/

Comment: I guess you're missing the point. Having a whole bunch of selectors, each for every case one can think of, isn't an elegant or practical solution. I definitely agree that the selectors you're coming up with "work," though.

Answer (score -3):

```
$('h1').next().find('img').first()
```

This should find next img tag in the next sibling

---

Edited:

```
$('h1').nextAll().find('img').first()
```

This should find next img tag in all of next siblings

Comment: This will only work if the `<img>` is a child of the next sibling of `<h1>`.