# How to replace div background with whichever img src comes next in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this header on about 400 pages:

```
<div class="header">
</div>
```

Then later on down in the HTML there will inevitably be an image, eg:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

What I want to do is have JS or JQuery search down the markup for the very next img tag that appears, and replace the header with:

```
<div class="header" style="background-image:image.png">
</div>
```

Is this even possible? This Stack question has a way of getting the next image: [how to get the next image tag after specific dom tag, sibling or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920867/how-to-get-the-next-image-tag-after-specific-dom-tag-sibling-or-not) but I cannot figure out how to set that image as the background, as per the desired result above.

Comment: in the AA on the link,  `$h1.css("background-image", result.src);`

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the CSS of the H1? Rather than div.header?

Comment: i don't see a div.header in the accepted answer, but surely you can alter the selectors yourself to make it work anywhere...

Comment: I added: 
    var arthead = $(".header");
and
    arthead.css("background-image", result.src);
and it didn't seem to change anything...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) which will allow you to specify a CSS property value.

`elem.css('background-image', url);` will do the trick.

But the vanilla JS way to do it is with `elem.style.backgroundImage = url;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `:first` jQuery selector.

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.header').css('background-image', $('.header img:first').attr('src'));
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$(".header").each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).next('img').attr('src') + ')');
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c5zeghjs/)